# Issue while connecting a FTP server through public IP

Tags: windows, networking, router, ftp, windows-11

I am using my personal PC to setup a FTP server. I have set with the following configurations:

[FTP config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z9Msb.png)

FTP site / folder settings is as follows:

[folder settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/emWz3.png)

[folder settings -2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KkciJ.png)

I am able to connect to FTP server internally using the private IP address.

[internal ip connection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yVyCU.png)

I have configured port forwarding on the router side to allow FTP access.

[port forwarding at router end](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uv70C.png)

Also, I setup the following configuration on Router knowing it won't affect the ftp connections. Just want to be sure if it is hinders:

[other router settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ei4d4.png)

I have also added the FTP server to the list of application to be supported by Windows Firewall. Anything else to do?

[windows firewall settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/44Ncl.png)

When I try to connect to FTP server using public IP, it is not giving me any results.

Comment: No errors observed.. I just took a trace... while using my mobile with data connection to try access the ftp server.. it just timeouts.. 

Trace attached:

https://we.tl/t-vJeGQ2A5IS

Comment: Are you using passive or active mode of FTP? Is the firewall configured to allow the server to establish the FTP data channel after receiving a connection on the command channel? Why FTP and not something more secure/unproblematic?

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick - It is first time for me to setup a FTP server. I thought FTP server is easier. This is for my own use to access some files from my personal PC -1  when I am away working (from my personal PC -2). Is there any easier alternative to FTP?

Comment: Most firewalls have a special setting for FTP but I would use SCP as it is simpler from a firewalls perspective and has security advantages

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick I tried setting up the SFTP server. Again the same thing --> I am able to access it using internal ip address but not through external ip address. :(

Answer (score 0):

I have moved to SFTP as it is simpler...

Adding more info: [Unable to connect to SFTP server using a Public IP address](https://superuser.com/questions/1790365/unable-to-connect-to-sftp-server-using-a-public-ip-address)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).