# Share directory with big files between PCs

Tags: windows, networking, network-shares, sharing

I have two PCs (say Personal and Official) located at 2 different sites running on two different ISPs. I want to transfer files between both PCs as part of daily work. These files are really huge (100-200GBs of data). I tried setting up a SFTP server on a machine but since my ISP supports CG-NAT it didnt work as it should.

I tried setting up a private torrent for the folder but it crashes :(

Is there any solution which solves this purpose?

Please see: Both are running on Windows-10 & 11 respectively.

Comment: I would use a cloud service for this. That'd be OneDrive or Dropbox or similar.

Comment: Have you tried https://justbeamit.com

Comment: Or maybe something [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/selfhosted/comments/k34t1l/self_hosted_peertopeer_file_sending/)?

Answer (score 0):

I have created a SFTP server and using my public IPV6 address for users to connect.

Adding info: [Unable to connect to SFTP server using a Public IP address](https://superuser.com/questions/1790365/unable-to-connect-to-sftp-server-using-a-public-ip-address)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).